# Is there anyway to download files from http without changing the original file's name in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

http://api.brain-map.org/grid_data/download/1954

The above link is an example what I want to download. I guess it's 301 redirection? To be honest, I'm using a software resembles to FlashGet to download multiple links like the one above right now. But I'm still interested whether there's another function such as websave()/urlwrite in Matlab. But it seems if I want to use websave() or urlwrite(), I must change the file to a new name in the function. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *[urlread2](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2)*, its a contribution on the Matlab File Exchange from a well known authors.

Amongst other things it can do, calling:

```
[data, resp] = urlread2(url);
```

will give you raw information from the HTTP response. You can retrieve the filename by parsing the string in `resp.allHeaders.Content_Disposition`, then save the file yourself with the correct name.

Comment: Thx! Do you know what kind of redirection of the link I attahed?

Comment: there's no redirect, the server is sending binary data back Content-Type on the response is 'application/octet-stream'

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB can run Java code. Try this code to get file name

```
s = 'http://api.brain-map.org/grid_data/download/1954';
url = java.net.URL(s);
tmp = url.openConnection;
descr = char(tmp.getHeaderField('Content-Disposition'));
```